Golang, how to solve html/template unexpected {{end}}
I am currently in university and we started using Golang to make sites. My assignment is to create a website, but I am currently stuck in this one problem I do not know how to solve. My task is to create a website like Reddit and when I try to show a post page I get the error "template: post.html:28: unexpected {{end}}"
I am trying this :
tpl, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/post.html")

and my template is this:
<article class="post">
            {{ .Post }}
            <h1>{{ .Title }}</h1>
            <p>{{ .Content }}</p>
            <div class="post-meta">
                <span class="author">Posted by {{ .User_ID}} on {{ .Date }}</span>
            </div>
            {{ end }}
</article>


Solve it by writing correct template code. {{end}} is a closing action for certain actions like {{if}} {{range}} etc. If you didn't open such a block that doesn't need a {{end}} closing action, simply don't use it.
